# Estrogen level after sex

Tags: dermatology, endocrinology, hair, sexuality, estrogen

Estrogen levels ought to elevate after having sex in women and thus improve skin and hair quality. I do not find the scientific proof for this statement. Who can help?

Comment: Hair grows at about half a millimeter per day and skin cells are replaced every 10-30 days. How would something as brief as a sexual encounter have a visible effect on things that take weeks to appear?

Comment: "Estrogen levels ought to elevate after having sex..." Why do you say this? Do you have any reason why this should be true? There might be a good reason you can't find proof for that statement.

Comment: It is written in several publications. They quote an American Study of The American Health ministry. I would like to see that publication, but do not find it.